# Detect number of columns in a bootstrap grid with javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, html, multiple-columns

I am using a javascript to set the height of divs to make sure that the each row of divs in a grid has the same height

The divs are each setup as:

`<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">`

So that on different size devices they show as either 3 column, 2 column or a single column

My javascript is as follows:

```
function fitRows( $container, options ) {
var cols = options.numColumns,
   $els = $container.children(),
   maxH = 0, j,
   doSize;

doSize = ( $container.width() != $els.outerWidth(true) );

$els.each(function( i, p ) {

  var $p = $( p ), h;

  $p.css( 'min-height', '' );
  if ( !doSize ) return;

  h = $p.outerHeight( true );
  if ( i % 3 == cols - 1 ) {
     for ( j=cols;j;j--) {
        $p.css( 'min-height', maxH );
        $p = $p.prev();
     }
     maxH = 0;
  } else {

     maxH = Math.max( h, maxH );
  }

   });
}

$(function() {

   var opts = {
  numColumns: 3
  };

   fitRows( $( '.tiles' ), opts );

   $( window ).on( 'resize', function() {
  fitRows( $( '.tiles' ), opts );
   });
   $( window ).on( 'load', function() {
  fitRows( $( '.tiles' ), opts );
   });
});
```

This works perfectly when either 3 columns or 1 column is shown. Is there anyway to detect when 2 columns are being display and change the javascript accordingly

Comment: Would `display: table/table-cell` work as well for equal heights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I went with an if statement based on the size of the window to workout the number of columns

```
if ($(window).width() >= 992 ){
    $columns = 3;
}
else if ($(window).width() >= 768 ){
    $columns = 2;
}       
else {
    $columns = 1;   
}                       
var opts = {    
    numColumns: $columns
};
```

and then replaced `i % 3` with `i % cols`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `MediaQueryList`, which is supported by modern browsers.  A polyfill is available for older browsers.

**Usage**

if(`window.matchMedia("(min-width:480px)").matches) //do something`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Testing_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

Javascript could "know" which columns we're positioned on the next row in two ways:

- Use media-query-like javascript to determine when the wrapping occurs. Modernizr is great for this.
- Check the `offset.top` of each column and compare. If they're next to each other the values will match. Any column at a different offset will obviously not be on the same row

It's a lot better/cleaner/easier to read than trying to judge based on element widths, etc.

However, you may want to look into `display: table/table-cell` for the columns and their parent, because that will give you equal heights as well.

I'm not fully sure I know what you're counting but I assume that you have columns that stop floating next to each other for smaller devices.

Comment: Unfortunately neither offset().top nor any other positioning value reflects the actual position, its always the value from the parent element or 0.